# Running Multiple Installations with System-Reboot Inbetween them

Tags: windows, batch-file, operating-system, patch

Currently I have a set of software-Installations(and their paths) that i have to install on my Windows Machine.
What I do now is -- Hit RUN every time and type in the software installation path into it..

What I want is to design a Batch file which would install all the applications and REBOOT my system after every successful installation and then continue with the NEXT item in the list..
Is it possible using a .bat file ??

Comment: Can a Batch file be Persistent after a system Reboot ??

Comment: See the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't something batch was designed for, so this will be a bit hacky. It's not elegant by any means but give it a shot, it might work for you.

```
for /f %%a in (C:\files.txt) do (
start /wait %%a
exit /b
)
for /f "skip=1" %%b in ("C:\files.txt) do (
echo %%b >>C:\newfiles.txt    
)
xcopy C:\newfiles.txt C:\files.txt /y
del C:\newfiles.txt /f /q
shutdown /r /t 0 /f
```

The idea being that you have a text file with the paths of the executables that you want to install. It will go through and execute the first file in the list, wait for it to complete, then re-write the list without the file it just installed.

This is dependend on the setup file having no user interaction and exiting by itself, or maybe it's just to make things easier - in which case just go through each install yourself, and when it finishes the batch file will do the rest.

On the note of rebooting and continuing you will either need to run the batch file again yourself or put it in the registry to start up itself, the latter command being

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v "MyBatchInstaller" /d "C:\MyBatchFile.bat" /f
```

Hope this helps